# How to simultaneously scroll two chart using AchartEngine?

Tags: android, achartengine

I have an android application that uses AchartEngine to display two graphs. Everything is up and running and I can scroll each chart individually. However, I would like to be able to make the two charts scroll simultaneously, meaning that if scroll one chart, the other gets scrolled by the same amount. Does anyone have any pointers on how to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listener on scrolling on each chart and change the other chart accordingly, something like this:

For the first chart mChartView_1

```
mChartView_1.addPanListener(new PanListener() {
    public void panApplied() {
        mRenderer_2.setRange(new double[] { 
            mRenderer_1.getXAxisMin(), 
            mRenderer_1.getXAxisMax(), 
            mRenderer_1.getYAxisMin(), 
            mRenderer_1.getYAxisMax() 
        });
    }
  });
```

and for the second chart mChartView_2

```
mChartView_2.addPanListener(new PanListener() {
    public void panApplied() {
        mRenderer_1.setRange(new double[] { 
            mRenderer_2.getXAxisMin(), 
            mRenderer_2.getXAxisMax(), 
            mRenderer_2.getYAxisMin(), 
            mRenderer_2.getYAxisMax() 
        });
    }
  });
```

Should work, but I didn't try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Add repaint() function to the above 2 code snippets. It will work only when we repaint.

```
mChartView_2.repaint();    // for mChartView_1 pan listener

mChartView_1.repaint();    // for mChartView_2 pan listener
```

Its late. But, hope it helps future readers.